# DbUp - Loop script for different variable values

Tags: dbup

I'm trying to loop on a list of ID's in order to execute the same query with its different values.

I was thinking about using IScript to create this loop using C#, but I don't have access to the variables that are passed when using `.WithVariable()`.

Is there any way to perform this action?

Comment: Did you find out how to do this?

Comment: Still have no answer @ovolo